# How do you write the optional comparison functor for a map?

Tags: c++

Suppose I had: `map<map_data, int, decltype(compare)> the_map`

```
struct map_data{
   int data1;
   int data2;
}
```

I've tried writing compare as:

```
struct
{
   bool operator()(map_data one, map_data two) const
   {
      if(one.data1 == two.data1)
         return one.data2 > two.data2;
      else
         return one.data1 < two.data1;
   }
}compare;
```

but I get a lot of compile errors.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You coded the comparison the way that the `data1` is ordered in ascending order, but the tie breaking goes in the reverse order. Is that intentional?

Comment: _What_ errors......???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it would have to be like so:

```
struct compare
{
   bool operator()(map_data const& one, map_data const& two) const
   {
      if(one.data1 == two.data1)
         return one.data2 > two.data2;
      else
         return one.data1 < one.data2;
   }
};
```

Also, you do not need `decltype`. Use the name of your functor class directly:

```
std::map<map_data, int, compare> the_map;
//                      ^^^^^^^
```

Here you can see a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/48Ihhx%24144) of the above code compiling.

Comment: Okay, all good advice, but you did not identify any blocks to compilation.

Comment: The question asks for assistance with compilation errors. Your answer does not identify the cause of compilation errors. Mine does!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Right, yours does. But I don't think this answer is so bad that is worth downvoting (btw, I am not the downvoter of your answer).

Comment: I only downvoted because you didn't answer the question. I think it's a _great_ answer to some other question, though!

Answer (score 1):

**You forgot the semicolon after the `map_data` definition. Fixing that, [compilation in C++11 is successful](https://ideone.com/jE1ZeS)**:

```
#include <map>

using std::map;

struct map_data{
   int data1;
   int data2;
};

struct
{
   bool operator()(map_data one, map_data two) const
   {
      if(one.data1 == two.data1)
         return one.data2 > two.data2;
      else
         return one.data1 < two.data1;
   }
}compare;

int main() {
    map<map_data, int, decltype(compare)> the_map;
}
```

---

However it seems a bit wasteful to require C++11 `decltype` for this, and to instantiate an object `compare` when all you really need is the type.

Why not [be conventional](https://ideone.com/A78TDP)?

```
#include <map>

using std::map;

struct map_data {
   int data1;
   int data2;
};

struct map_data_comparator
{
   bool operator()(const map_data& one, const map_data& two) const
   {
      if (one.data1 == two.data1)
         return one.data2 > two.data2;
      else
         return one.data1 < two.data1;
   }
};

int main()
{
    map<map_data, int, map_data_comparator> the_map;
}
```

You can see that I've also made your comparator arguments *const references*, just for the sake of it really.